# Can I output text/variables that are not part of a graph to a figure window?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

In Matlab Can I output text/variables to a figure window that are not part of a graph?  For example.

I have a image that I am running a filter through.  I want to display the new image with statistics (time ran,max,min,standard deviation) to show that the filter is changing.  I can display the image just fine, but I cant seem to figure out a way to display the statistics next to the image in the figure window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot outside of the figure like this:

```
fig = figure(1);clf;
ax = gca;
plot([0 0 1 1 0],[0 1 1 0 0]);
text(1.05,0.5,'test');
```

You can modify the size of the figure and of the axis using:

```
fig.Position = [0 500 860 420];
ax.Position=[0.1 0.1 0.7 0.7];
```

Comment: How do I avoid the text being printed onto the actual image itself?  The text function works great, but I want it to printed outside the graph on the same window.

Comment: Always give it a bigger x coordinate than the maximum of your axis. You can request that maximum using `ax.XLim`